# How do I verify if my USPS IMpb barcode is correct?

Tags: usps, code128

I'm writing software using the [USPS Intelligent Package Barcode (IMpb)](https://ribbs.usps.gov/barcode_cert/documents/tech_guides/ParcelLabelingGuide.pdf)

I have to send my labels to DHL for verification, but to avoid embarassment I'd like to try to verify them myself - at least to make sure things like checksum are correct and that they're the correct length.

Are there any tools, or verification 'snippets' to do that?

Comment: Come on, 32k and you are asking for tool recommendations?  Hang your head in shame.

Comment: actually no - I've got some useful information I'm currently altruistically writing as an answer for others. hoping to get to 32.01k

Comment: Actually yes.  You're asking for a tool recommendation.  "Are there any tools to do that?"  <-- see that?  There's a close reason for that.  Your edit helps, but still, if you suggest a tool in an answer you're putting yourself at risk for getting dinged for spam.  Algorithm is fine and great, tho.

Comment: I was posting this mainly for the google trick - I've never been a fan of the tool policy. Some 'tool questions' get out of control but many many I've found answer to don't and have been invaluable and on-topic

Answer (score 1):

#### To verify check digit

Just [google the number](https://www.google.com/search?q=4205493592612999963862100506324936&oq=420&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j0l2.1539j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=4205493592612999963862100506324936) - if it is a valid USPS package it will show up in the results.

If I change the last digit (check digit) from 6 to 7 then there are no results.
You can also see it's stripped off the beginning `42054935` which is the application identifier + zipcode.

[image]

#### To verify barcode itself

You can upload an image to this [online barcode reader](http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/default.aspx) and it will parse the barcode for you.
I'm not sure if it will give false positives if you don't have all the start and stop digits correct but it will show you that you've got the FNC1 digit correct. You can even upload a PDF.

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to flag this as spam, due to our convo, but keep an eye on this in case others do.  You'll be able to delete it before you get hit for 100 rep for a post deleted as spam.